# Deploying Django on Heroku smart-open Causing Failure

Tags: python, django, heroku, devops

Trying to deploy Django project to Heroku I get the following error:

```
python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully. exit code: 1
error in smart_open setup command: 'python_requires' must be a string containing valid version specifiers; Invalid specifier: '>=3.6.*'
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: metadata-generation-failed
```

Tried multiple versions of smart-open and tried removing it from requirements.txt, the invalid specifier is NOT in my requirements.txt (this is: smart-open==4.1.0) or I have tried multiple other versions, all break the build. I’ve tried changing setup tools on Heroku to eg setuptools==40.3.0, no dice (same errors).